# Collecting name and email in form

Tags: php, html, security, forms

On a website I'm working on, I would like to collect a user's name and email address to add to a mailing list.

My question is NOT how to do this, I know that part.

What I would like to know is, how would I do this *so as to avoid spam, robots, etc*?

I would like to prevent as much non-human interaction as possible, while keeping the HTML interface as easy to use as possible.

I am using PHP as a back-end, if it matters.

Thanks,
Austin

Answer (score 0):

- [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha) – I suggest use some sort of 3D CAPTCHA, because it's much harder (maybe even impossible?) for robots to read.
- Use Javascript, somehow.
- Question that only human can answer.